# Using Trusted Platform module in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, tpm

I have a signing key that I need to safely store.

What I used to do, was store it directly in the Hardware available on that same host (TPM2.0, using pkcs11 API).
Now I am moving my services to Kubernetes, I have tried googling "Kubernetes TPM" but everything I have found was securing Kubernetes with a remote TPM (Via a Key Management System), not on the host itself.
Is using the hardware located on the node an anti-pattern (Because I see very little about using the node TPM with Kubernetes)?
What is the thing that is most commonly done to protect those signing keys (aside from KMS)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Run your kubernetes cluster
- Deploy [**Hashicorp Vault**](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm) as one of your first applications.
- Then configure it according to your needs. i.e.  https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/seal/pkcs11

In this era, APIs are the way.